# daisy chained layer 2

Tags: ethernet

I just read an article about how daisy chaining switches is bad, that one should always do an Ethernet drop directly to the main switch rather than passing by the others, because power issues will cause the people using the network to lose more money than it costs to drop the Ethernet cable.

My data volumes are never going to go beyond 20mbps. Iff somebody has a problem, they're in their house, I give them the solution of turning off their electric service, then turning it on.

Do I really gain by running the extra ether cable?

Comment: I'm sorry, **what?** None of this makes any sense - what power issues are you talking about? Daisy chaining can be bad due to throughput, but it all depends on what you're doing and your physical infrastructure.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't resist trying to Google, and I wonder if this is the article you're referring to:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/project-management/only-novices-daisy-chain-switches/3854

> Here’s the cost justification: If you don’t run new cable and you
>   depend upon daisy-chained connections, trouble will arise — it’s a
>   question of when, not if. This is true even if you go so far as
>   powering the extraneous switches using a battery backup, which helps
>   reduce the number of network failures. Each time a failure arises, the
>   client’s going to suffer an outage, which means staff can’t work and
>   that translates to lost revenue. Then the client calls you, which
>   results in a service call. Maybe you power cycle a switch or two or
>   even replace one of the extraneous switches that’s been fried by a
>   lightning strike, resulting in another $75 in parts and $125 in labor.
>   Consider that scenario may repeat itself three of four times over four
>   or so years, and the client’s looking at having lost hours of staff
>   productivity and maybe a thousand dollars in switches and service.

In my opinion, the article isn't wrong as such, but it is badly written and unnecessarily focused on failures due to power. All the issues he alludes to are problems of management, documentation and design.

You **should** avoid using dasiychained switches where possible, but there's nothing inherently wrong with it in certain cases.

Running a cable all the way back may not be cost effective, (Remember, Ethernet has distance limits, and fiber will be even more expensive especially if your infrastructure isn't geared up for it) and the access layer of a network will nearly always have single points of failure. If the network is documented, then these should take minutes to diagnose.

I also don't really see his point about 'fried' switches, either. Whether the switch is daisychained or not - if it's going to go up in smoke, it's going to go up in smoke.

Finally, it's pretty rare that I see access layer switches on UPS anyway. Some people do it, and it's nice to have, but in the case of a power outage then the devices connected to it will probably not be on UPS anyway.

Ultimately, it seems that his real gripe is with networks that grow organically, with no forethought and without consultation. I agree with this completely, but it's that there is a hidden switch behind a cupboard in the first place that's the problem, not how it's connected to the rest of the network.

Just to reiterate - I'm not saying daisy-chaining is a good idea, but I do find that article very flawed in its reasoning.

Finally, your core question still makes no real sense to me.